# How to merge multiple rows into single cell based on id and then count?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

How to merge multiple rows into single cell based on id using PySpark? I have a dataframe with ids and products. First I want to merge the products with the same id together into a list, then I want to count the number of occurrences of each unique list.

Input example 1:

```
id,product
1,HOME
1,mobile
2,watch
2,mobile
3,HOME
3,mobile
4,cd
4,music
4,video
```

Output:

```
product,count
HOME-mobile,2
mobile-watch,1
cd-music-video,1
```

Example 2 with sql code:

Input example:

```
cloths,brad
cloths,edu
cloths,keith
cloths,stef
enter,andr
enter,char
enter,danny
enter,lucas
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
   SS.SEC_NAME,
   STUFF((SELECT '- ' + US.USR_NAME 
          FROM USRS US
          WHERE US.SEC_ID = SS.SEC_ID
          ORDER BY USR_NAME
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [SECTORS/USERS]
FROM SALES_SECTORS SS
GROUP BY SS.SEC_ID, SS.SEC_NAME
ORDER BY 1
```

Output:

```
cloths,brad-edu-keith-stef
enter,andr-char-danny-lucas
```

In this example the output does not have the count, but it should be included.

I would like to solve this in PySpark instead of sql/pig.

Comment: It is a simple use case for pyspark. Show us what have you tried??

Comment: ia m new in pyspark i already try with pig  i dont know how do with pyspark so i need  help for that                                                                                       group_url = GROUP logdata by (url);
X = FOREACH group_url {
     unique_users = DISTINCT logdata.name; 
     GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT(unique_users) AS UniqueUsers,unique_users as name, 
COUNT(logdata) as counts;}


STORE X INTO 'output/bigdata_analytics_cleaned';

Comment: @kumar: Please use the edit functionality and add the code to the question itself and not in a comment. Furthermore, the code you pasted here does not seem to contain the same column names as in the question and seems to do other things as well.

Comment: @kumar: From what you have said, I tried to add some more description to the question, please check so it's correct. I also added an answer that I hope can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this is PySpark by using `groupby`. First group on the id column and merge the products together into a single, sorted list. To get the count of the number of such lists, use `groupby` again and aggregate by `count`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = (df
  .groupby("id")
  .agg(F.concat_ws("-", F.sort_array(F.collect_list("product"))).alias("products"))
  .groupby("products")
  .agg(F.count("id")).alias("count"))
```

This should give you a dataframe like this:

```
+--------------+-----+
|      products|count|
+--------------+-----+
|   HOME-mobile|    2|
|  mobile-watch|    1|
|cd-music-video|    1|
+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks

i need data output colum record seprate with '-' EX:mobile- watch

Comment: @kumar: For the second example (sql) you don't use a count. Is that needed or not?

Comment: @kumar: Updated

Comment: count needed thnks

Comment: Is there a way to do this and still keep the 'id' field?

Comment: @Matt: If you want to keep the `id` column it sounds like you want to do something quite different from the above. Depending on what you are after it could be either not doing the second `groupby`-`agg` computation or use `F.collect_list("id")` instead of `F.count("id")` in the second aggregation.