# Aggregate field by ID and retain ID as column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Basically, I'm trying to modify the accepted response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791878/how-to-merge-multiple-rows-into-single-cell-based-on-id-and-then-count) to retain the id field which is used in the aggregation.

So if my input dataframe looks like this:

```
id   |  author
a    |  Smith
a    |  Jones
b    |  Kabir
c    |  Chen
c    |  Zhang
c    |  Culver
```

Ideally, I would like my output to look like this:

```
id | authors             | count
a  | Smith, Jones        |   2
b  | Kabir               |   1
c  | Chen, Zhang, Culver |   3
```

I've been able to use the following command to get pretty close:

```
    myDF2 = (myDF 
                .groupby("id") 
                .agg(concat_ws(", ", sort_array(collect_list("author"))).alias("authors")) 
                .groupby("authors") 
                .agg(count("id")).alias("count") 
             )
```

This produces the aggregation that I want but I can't figure out how to keep or add the `id` field in the output.

Comment: just group by both authors and id in the second group by

Comment: would it be possible to take the [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size) of the authors column instead of the second groupBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1

Before concatenating the items within the list, you could count it using [`size`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
myDf2 = myDf.groupBy("id").agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_list('author')).alias('authors'))
myDf2 = myDf2.select(
   F.col('id'),
   F.concat_ws(", ",F.col('authors')).alias('authors'),
   F.size('authors').alias('count')
)

myDf2.show()
```

***Outputs***

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|            authors|count|
+---+-------------------+-----+
|  c|Chen, Culver, Zhang|    3|
|  b|              Kabir|    1|
|  a|       Jones, Smith|    2|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

In my output `c` was the first row, if the order is important you may order by `id` using

```py
myDf2 = myDf2.orderBy(F.col('id'))
```

### Approach 2

Similarly uou may use the [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.count.html) in your first aggregation

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
myDf2 = myDf.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.concat_ws(", ",F.sort_array(F.collect_list('author'))).alias('authors'),
    F.count('author').alias('count'),
)

myDf2.show()
```

***Outputs***

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|            authors|count|
+---+-------------------+-----+
|  c|Chen, Culver, Zhang|    3|
|  b|              Kabir|    1|
|  a|       Jones, Smith|    2|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

### Setup

```py
myDFData="""
id   |  author
a    |  Smith
a    |  Jones
b    |  Kabir
c    |  Chen
c    |  Zhang
c    |  Culver 
"""

myDf =sparkSession.createDataFrame([{"id":linesplit[0].strip(), "author":linesplit[1].strip()} for linesplit in [line.split("|") for line in myDFData.strip().split("\n")[1:]]])
myDf.show()
```

***Outputs***

```
+------+---+
|author| id|
+------+---+
| Smith|  a|
| Jones|  a|
| Kabir|  b|
|  Chen|  c|
| Zhang|  c|
|Culver|  c|
+------+---+
```